# How to control subplot main figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to control which figures the data should be plotted in? In this example below, I am trying to plot my data in two separate figures (a and b block of code) which is working fine. However, I want to come back to figure 1 to plot as my data is organised differently, but c-block is plotting on the latest figure rather than figure 1 as I specified in `figure = plt.figure(1)`. What is it I'm doing wrong, please?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#a-block
figure = plt.figure(1)
figure, axisArr = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(8.27, 11.70), sharex=True)
axisArr[0].plot(range(10), '-', color = 'red')
axisArr[1].plot(range(20), ':', color = 'yellow')
axisArr[0].plot(range(30), '.', color = 'blue')

#b-block
figure = plt.figure(2)
figure, axisArr = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(8.27, 11.70), sharex=True)
axisArr[0].plot(range(10), '-', color = 'red')
axisArr[1].plot(range(20), ':', color = 'black')
axisArr[0].plot(range(30), '.', color = 'blue')

#c-block
figure = plt.figure(1)
axisArr[2].plot(range(10), '-', color = 'red')
axisArr[3].plot(range(10), '-', color = 'green')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to name the different figures and axes array by the same name. You thereby loose the handle to the axes you want to plot to. Instead, use different names.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure1, axisArr1 = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(8.27, 11.70), sharex=True)
axisArr1[0].plot(range(10), '-', color = 'red')
axisArr1[1].plot(range(20), ':', color = 'yellow')
axisArr1[0].plot(range(30), '.', color = 'blue')


figure2, axisArr2 = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(8.27, 11.70), sharex=True)
axisArr2[0].plot(range(10), '-', color = 'red')
axisArr2[1].plot(range(20), ':', color = 'black')
axisArr2[0].plot(range(30), '.', color = 'blue')


axisArr1[2].plot(range(10), '-', color = 'red')
axisArr1[3].plot(range(10), '-', color = 'green')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks that explains it! I had hundreds of charts to plot hence I am looping through all of them and can't give different variable names. Is there a workaround than giving different axes array names etc? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Giving a name to a variable is always possible. Maybe you want to store the handle in some list?

Comment: The problem is the data is not organised (pulling from a huge database), and I was going to instruct. If you find AB data plot in subplot 3 of figure 1, if you find BA data plot in Fig2-subplot1, but if there is an instance of AB again go back to Fig1-subplot 3 etc. I get your point though `figure` and `axisArr` are instances, once the same name used the previous reference to that instance is lost. At least I know what the problem is, thanks for taking the time!